# Native .js code cannot resolve localhost but a Postman request can

Tags: postman, localhost, resolve

I can call my endpoint using Postman eg, GET : http://localhost:500/foo but when running some native .js code and executing it through npm it cannot resolve the host; is there a reason as to why this happens?

My hosts file contains:
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

Comment: Please post the code you are having problems with.

Comment: I doubt that would help...

It's just a get to a ping endpoint on the server

Comment: http://localhost:5000/_system/ping -> pong


http://127.0.0.1:5000/_system/ping -> 404 page not found